# Run javascript function in sequence

Tags: javascript, axios

```
function main(){
   function_A();
   function_B();
}
function function_A(){
   axios(....).then(res=>{console.log("get response of A")});
}
function function_B(){
   axios(....).then(res=>{console.log("get response of B")});
}
```

Assume that I have a main function to control the flow  of a program, if I cannot edit the function A and B, how can I run them in sequence (function_B should wait function_A response before start)?

Comment: `return axios ...` and use `function_A.then(function_B)` - but since you can not edit `function_A` or `function_B`, you're basically screwed - whoever wrote those functions should be shot

Comment: Alternatively `await function_A(); function_B()`

Answer (score 0):

In the way this is currently coded - you can't. Both functions - A and B are synchronous. This means they will fire in the order they are invoked. What happens within them, though, is asynchronous and since you can't edit function A, you can't "attach" to the settle of the promise within it - be it resolve or reject.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Smytt suggested, you won't be able to the way it is currently implemented. We would need to edit `functionA()` and define the *what* we are waiting for.

Promises do exactly what your question asks

```
function function_A(){
   return axios(....)
      .then(res => {
         console.log("get and return response of A");
         return res;
    }).catch(...);

}
function function_B(){
   axios(....).then(res => {console.log("get response of B")});
}
```

You can call it like:

```
function_A().then(result => function_B()).catch(...);
```

Note also that the `async` keyword is **optional** to signify an asynchronous function that returns a promise. This was created so we can use asynchronous functions as if they were synchronous.

```
async function function_A(){
   return await axios(....)
      .then(res => {
         console.log("get and return response of A");
         return res;
    }).catch(...);

}

async function function_B(){
   await axios(....).then(res => {console.log("get response of B")});
}
```